# MSVC debugging symbols

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a .net application that locks up after running for about an hour. I was hoping to do an autopsy on its threads to find out what state each is in. The problem is that after attaching a debugger (MSVC12) there is no obvious way of getting human readable stacktraces. The application is launched using an external test harness, so I cannot easily start it in the debugger.

I have created directory c:/symbols, set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH to Srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols , and checked in Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols that both "environment variable" and "Microsoft servers" are ticked.

The pdb is present in the same directory as the executable, however I also stored in c:/symbols using symstore (that came with what appears to be the W8 SDK though I am still on W7). There is a newly created subdirectory in c:/symbols though symstore said it found an ID (0000001) then stored 0 files (it also says there were 0 errors and 0 ignored files).

The stacktraces I get tend to be fairly short and some appear identical (idle threads perhaps?), e.g.

```
ntdll.dll!0000000076ff137a()    Unknown
KernelBase.dll!000007fefd071a7a()   Unknown
kernel32.dll!0000000076d91559() Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!000007fef171e9e2()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!000007fef12935f8()  Unknown
0000000008e20298()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!000007fef12935f8()  Unknown
00000000572fd470()  Unknown
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you've got an unmanaged debugger attached.  From the Tools + Attach to Process, select the process and don't forget to pick the type of debugger you want.  Click the Select button if necessary, you want "Managed" ticked.

You do have a problem with symbols, it should have downloaded the symbols for ntdll.dll etc from the symbol server.  Hard to diagnose from the provided info, you certainly should not be using "symstore" or have to set the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable, ticking the "Microsoft servers" checkbox is sufficient.  Do make sure that the c:\symbols directory is accessible, favor a path in your c:\users home directory to be safe.  You can get extra diagnostics from the Debug + Windows + Modules window.  Right-click an entry and choose Symbol Load Information.

Comment: Many thanks! I am afraid I simply didn't know it was possible to attach the debugger from within MSVC (rather than from task manager). I guess there must be a manual somewhere :-( It loaded the symbols fine after I told it to disable the "just my code" option.